# C - input 2 values, return 2 values to MAIN. swapping

Tags: c, function, return, swap

I need to make a program to arrange 4 numbers in ascending order, like 9 2 8 3 to 2 3 8 9.
So i thought of the logic by using swap. I would be using if/else or switch statements but first i need to solve this problem below.
I want to input 2 integers (to compare later), then swap them and return it to main function. How do i do this. Please provide the best solution though i haven't been taught pointers, structs etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int swap(int x, int y)
{   
int c;
    c = x;
    x = y;
    y = c;
    return x, y;
}

int main()
{
int a = 5, b = 7;

    printf("a=%d b=%d\n", a, b);
    swap(a, b);
    printf("a=%d b=%d\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

I want final output as 7, 5. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return x, y;
```

You can not return more than one value from a function, you can pass a pointer and then modify his content:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *x, int *y)
{   
    int c;

    c = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = c;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5, b = 7;

    printf("a=%d b=%d\n", a, b);
    swap(&a, &b);
    printf("a=%d b=%d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, you just needed to write a and b in place of x, y. God bless you

Answer (score 1):

Pass Address of variables a and b

```
void swap(int *x, int *y)
{   
int c;
    c = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = c;

}
```

call from main `swap(&a,&b);`

print a and b values in main.

Comment: sorry I need to use word address there instead of reference.